# How do I change the schema for both a table and a foreign key?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following simplified database access layer and two tables:

```
class DataAccessLayer():
    def __init__(self):
        conn_string = "mysql+mysqlconnector://root:root@localhost/"
        self.engine = create_engine(conn_string)
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)
        Session = sessionmaker()
        Session.configure(bind=self.engine)
        self.session = Session()


class MatchesATP(Base):
    __tablename__ = "matches_atp"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "belgarath", "extend_existing": True}

    ID_M = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ID_T_M = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("oncourt.tours_atp.ID_T"))


class TournamentsATP(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tours_atp"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "oncourt", "extend_existing": True}

    ID_T = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    NAME_T = Column(String(255))
```

I want to be able to switch the schema names for the two tables  to test databases as follows:

`belgarath` to `belgarath_test`

`oncourt` to `oncourt_test`

I've tried adding:

```
self.session.connection(execution_options={"schema_translate_map": {"belgarath": belgarath, "oncourt": oncourt}})
```

To the bottom of `DataAccessLayer` and then initialising the class with two variables as follows:

```
def __init__(self, belgarath, oncourt):
```

However, when I build the following query:

```
dal = DataAccessLayer("belgarath_test", "oncourt_test")
query = dal.session.query(MatchesATP)
print(query)
```

I get the following SQL:

```
SELECT belgarath.matches_atp.`ID_M` AS `belgarath_matches_atp_ID_M`, belgarath.matches_atp.`ID_T_M` AS `belgarath_matches_atp_ID_T_M`
FROM belgarath.matches_atp
```

This is still referencing the `belgarath` table.

I also can't figure out a way of changing the schema of the foreign key of `oncourt.tours_atp.ID_T` at the same time as the tables.

Are there individual solutions or a combined solution to my issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only took me 18 months to figure this out. Turns out I needed to add the `schema_translate_map` to an `engine` and then create the session with this `engine`:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


engine = create_engine(conn_str, echo=False)
schema_engine = engine.execution_options(schema_translate_map={<old_schema_name>: <new_schema_name>})
NewSession = sessionmaker(bind=schema_engine)
session = NewSession()
```

All ready to roll...

Answer (score 2):

You might wanna decorate your subclassed `Base` declarative model with the `@declared_attr` decorator.

Try this--

In a base class for your models, say `__init__.py`...

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr


SCHEMA_MAIN = 'belgarath'  # figure out how you want to retrieve this
SCHEMA_TEST = 'belgarath_test'

class _Base(object):

    @declared_attr
    def __table_args__(cls):
        return {'schema': SCHEMA_MAIN}

...
Base = declarative_base(cls=_Base)
Base.metadata.schema = SCHEMA_MAIN
```

Now that you have a  `Base` that subclasses `_Base` with the main schema already defined, all your other models will subclass `Base` and do the following:

```py
from . import Base, declared_attr, SCHEMA_TEST

class TestModel(Base):
    
    @declared_attr
    def __table_args__(cls):
        return {'schema': SCHEMA_TEST}
```

Changing a schema for a foreign key could look like this:

```py
class TournamentsATP(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tours_atp"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "oncourt", "extend_existing": True}

    ID_T = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    NAME_T = Column(String(255))

    match_id = Column('match_id', Integer, ForeignKey(f'{__table_args__.get("schema")}.matches_atp.id'))
```

Where `match_id` is a foreign key to `matches_atp.id` by using the `__table_args[`schema`]` element defined at the class level via `@declared_attr`.

Comment: Thanks for this! Few follow ups: 1. Any idea why ```schema_translate_map``` isn't working for me? 2. I'm new to ```__init__.py```... if I put the top block of code into ```__init__.py``` will this always import it if I import any module in the same directory? 3. Should ```MAIN_SCHEMA``` actually be ```SCHEMA_MAIN```? 4. I presume I'll need two variants of the ```_Base``` class? One for ```belgarath``` and one for ```oncourt```? 5. How would I switch between the two when I write a query?

Comment: 1. I'm not sure, sorry. From reading the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#schema-translating), it looks like it'll work when you use `Table` objects instead of the ORM/declarative class approach you currently use. I've actually haven't used the `schema_translate_map` execution option for a `connection`. I'll try it sometime.

2. I'm not sure I understand. The vars defined in `__init__.py` can be imported like `from . import Base, SCHEMA_MAIN, SCHEMA_TEST` by another file in the same dir.

3. I've fixed it. Should be `SCHEMA_MAIN` for consistency.

Comment: 4. In this case, you only need one `_Base`, though it defaults to `belgarath`. Using the `@declared_attr` decorator allows you to set the `__table_args__` property of a test subclass where you can define the test schema.

5. See #4.

Comment: Thanks. Will experiment with this. Did you see the final part of my question around how to change the schema of the foreign key at the same time?

Comment: The ```{__table_args__.get("schema")}``` is a masterstroke! Thanks a million. However, still massively stuck on the first part. Can I just check that the first code block goes in ```__init__.py``` and the second code block goes in the same file as my ```DataAccessLayer``` class? Looks like you've used ```TestModel``` in the second block but this will actually be one of my table classes in reality, e.g. ```MatchesATP```?

Comment: In which case how do I switch schemas from my third file where my app is? I currently import ```DataAccessLayer``` and all the table classes into that third file - that's where all the queries are. The way your second code block is configured then it looks like I'd always overwrite ```SCHEMA_MAIN``` with ```SCHEMA_TEST```? I'm also a bit confused around how I'd be able to change ```oncourt``` at the same time as ```belgarath```? You've been awesome so far - is there anyway you could expand your answer to show what goes in each of the three files, if indeed there are supposed to be three files?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your goal is to:

1. have dev/test/prod schemas on a single mysql host
2. allow your ORM classes to be flexible enough to be used in three different environments without modification

Then John has you most of the way to one type of solution. You could use `@declared_attr` to dynamically generate `__table_args__` as he has suggested.

You could also consider using something like [flask-sqlalchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/binds/#binds) that comes with a built-in solution for this:

```py
    import os

    DB_ENV = os.getenv(DB_ENV)

    
    SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
        'belgarath': 'mysql+mysqlconnector://root:root@localhost/belgarath{}'.format(DB_ENV),
        'oncourt': 'mysql+mysqlconnector://root:root@localhost/oncourt{}'.format(DB_ENV)
    }
    
    class MatchesATP(Base):
        __bind_key__ = "belgarath"
        ID_M = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        ID_T_M = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("oncourt.tours_atp.ID_T"))
    
    
    class TournamentsATP(Base):
        __bind_key__ = "oncourt"
        ID_T = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        NAME_T = Column(String(255))
```

Basically this method allows you to create a link to a schema (a bind key), and that schema is defined at run-time via the connection string. More information at the flask-sqlalchemy link.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'd rather not switch everything to flask-sqlalchemy at this stage but will definitely bear it in mind. I'm still not at all clear on how to implement the things John has recommended hence the bounty. I don't suppose you could take his answer and flesh it out based upon my comments? He's been radio silent for almost a week...

Comment: Bounty is expiring soon! Any chance you could look at this?