# How can I switch between schemas at the point of a query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

By way of an MRE I have a simple module called `query` that adds a record to the `Bet` table:

```
from container_test import Bet, DataAccessLayer

def main():
    dal = DataAccessLayer()
    dal.create_session()
    query_bets(dal)

def add_new_id(dal):
    new_id = {"id_": 3}
    dal.session.add(Bet(**new_id))
    dal.session.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`container_test` contains the following:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Bet(Base):

    __tablename__ = "bet"
    __table_args__ = ({"schema": "belgarath", "extend_existing": True})

    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class DataAccessLayer():

    def __init__(self):
        conn_string = "mysql+mysqlconnector://root:root@localhost/"
        self.engine = create_engine(conn_string)

    def create_session(self):
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)
        Session = sessionmaker()
        Session.configure(bind=self.engine)
        self.session = Session()
```

I want to be able to test the `query_bets` function and to do this I have created a simple `pytest` function in another file:

```
def test_add_new_id(
    create_dal, # creates an instance of a dal via conftest
    setup_teardown, # creates a blank belgarath_test schema and deletes afterwards via conftest
):
    expected = 3
    sandpit.add_new_id(create_dal)
    actual = query_bet(create_dal) # function that will return a scalar result
    assert actual == expected
```

However, I want to be able to change the standard `belgarath` schema to a test schema; `belgarath_test` so I don't risk the integrity of the main database. I think I need some kind of 'switch' I can activate in the `test_add_new_id` test function but I'm not sure how to create one.

I've been trying to follow the solution set out in this post: [How do I change the schema for both a table and a foreign key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63314315/11277108) however I'm struggling. I don't understand what it is that I need to do in the `test_add_new_id` test function to change the schema.

For reference I have created the following modules as per the solution:

`container_test`:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from base_class import SCHEMA_TEST, Base, declared_attr


class Bet(Base):

    @declared_attr
    def __table_args__(cls):
        return {'schema': SCHEMA_TEST}

    __tablename__ = "bet"

    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class DataAccessLayer():

    def __init__(self):
        conn_string = "mysql+mysqlconnector://root:root@localhost/"
        self.engine = create_engine(conn_string)

    def create_session(self):
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)
        Session = sessionmaker()
        Session.configure(bind=self.engine)
        self.session = Session()
```

`base_class`(I got an error trying to use `__init__.py`):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr

SCHEMA_MAIN = 'belgarath'  # figure out how you want to retrieve this
SCHEMA_TEST = 'belgarath_test'


class _Base():

    @declared_attr
    def __table_args__(cls):
        return {'schema': SCHEMA_MAIN}


Base = declarative_base(cls=_Base)
Base.metadata.schema = SCHEMA_MAIN
```

This successfully changes `belgarath` to `belgarath_test` but I only want that to happen when I'm running the `test_add_new_id` test function.

Comment: When running the tests, why not just point your application to a separate backup copy of the database?

Comment: I’d be happy to do that but I still would need to point the test script to that database? How would I do that?

Comment: @Gord - sorry I should have said thanks for replying!

Comment: You could construct your connection URI based on whether you are running in "test mode" or in "production mode". That could be controlled by an environment variable, or a command line argument, or even the name of the machine itself.

Comment: Really appreciate you trying to help! The challenge is that I have two schemas (```belgarath``` and ```oncourt```) in the database so I don't think I can specify a specific schema in the connection? I will also be building test scripts for ```oncourt``` too using ```oncourt_test```

Comment: Have both of the schemas in the test database?

Comment: Really your tests shouldn't even have the password to the production database...

Comment: @GordThompson - I think you may have cracked it with a really simple solution!! I already use the name of the machine to do a couple of things - pretty sure I can just extend this!!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than running the tests in a different schema in the same database, run the tests in a different database?

That will also improve test isolation, since the tests will no longer have the password to the production database, so a buggy test will not be able to destroy prod data.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for responding. This is only a personal project so I was hoping to avoid the complexity of having an actual test and production database as they'll both have to sit on my PC at home. Is there something I could do to enable the 'switching' in the short term?

Answer (score 1):

From sqlalchemy 1.1, you can change schema at runtime easily by using: [schema_translation_map](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/changelog/migration_11.html#multi-tenancy-schema-translation-for-table-objects).

As after discussion in comments, there is a requirement to use 4 schemas for a single session, it is not advised to create session repeatedly but simply use:

```
session.connection(execution_options={"schema_translate_map": {"belgarath": "belgarath_test"}})
```

The above statement will switch the schema to `belgarath_test`, similarly `oncourt` and `oncourt_test` can be used.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for this! Should the parameter actually be: `{"schema": "belgarath_test"}`? The issue I'm going to face is that I have two schemas in the same database and I'll need to change both of them over to their test versions. Not sure the above can work?

Comment: @Jossy
To change the schema for a session the script used is:
`session.connection(execution_options={"schema_translate_map": {"schema": "belgarath_test"}})`

You may change the schema before the test function is executed and revert it to the previous schema at the end.

Comment: Hi. I need two schemas in the session - `belgarath` and `oncourt` need to be switched to `belgarath_test` and `oncourt_test` respectively. `schema_translate_map` only seems to be able to change one schema per session?

Comment: @Jossy, have you tried using the function I mentioned multiple times for the same session? It should work any number of times.

Comment: No because that would obviously have been the logical thing to do! Right - I have a way forward - thanks and will check back in :)

Comment: @Jossy, sure. Let me know in case of any progress/issues.

Comment: You're a bloody genius! The answer above doesn't work but it got me on the right track. Running `create_session` for a second time overwrites the first session. However, I can run `create_session` then run `session.connection(execution_options={"schema_translate_map": {"belgarath": "belgarath_test"}})` followed by the `oncourt` equivalent and we're there! You have no idea how long I've been trying to solve this!!! Do you want to amend the answer to include dual schema changes and I'll mark as accepted?

Comment: @Jossy, thanks for your contribution as well :) let me update the answer.

Comment: Hi. Really sorry but I've not been able to replicate those first results. Not sure if it's an issue with this approach or my setup. Have another question open on SO here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/64361833/11277108